# swift - JSON accessing data

Tags: json, swift

I want to access json data:

```
   var foods:JSON?{
        didSet{
            self.setupFood()
        }
    }

    func setupFood(){

    return value = {
                  "total_count": 1, 
                  "foods": [{
                               "food_name": "fish",
                               "article_id": 122
                  }],
                  "table": {"table_id": 60,
                            "table_name": "far left"}
                  }
    }
```

I can access food name like this;

```
let foodName = self.foods?["food_name"].string
```

I cant find a way to acess table_name.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) library you can easily get your values like shown in below code:

```
let json = JSON(data: data)
let foodName = json["foods"][0]["food_name"].stringValue
println(foodName) //fish
```

Check out [THIS](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Get-JSON-Data-From-File) sample project for more Info.

Comment: Ok, I can access "food_name" like you said. But I can't access table_name.

Comment: You can access it this way: `let tableName = json["table"]["table_name"]`

Comment: I am getting correct value check it in my example project.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to cast table into a dictionary and then access that dictionary like so:

```
if let table = self.foods?["table"] as? NSDictionary {
    let tableName = table.objectForKey("table_name") as! String
}
```

Comment: "Cast from 'JSON?' to unrelated type 'NSDictionary' always fails" I get this error. I added my full code